# .net core log4net static log field

Tags: c#, log4net, .net-core, porting

I'm porting a project over to .Net Core and i want to use log4net for logging in .net core. my code in .net :

```
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

The problem in .net core is that "methodbase does not contain a definition for getCurrentMethod()"

i figured this should work (not 100% sure):

```
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof("MyClassName")) ;
```

but i want something that can be copied/pasted to any class without having to care about the classname ..., anyone know something that works ?

Comment: Don't copy in the first place, but use dependency injection?

Comment: What CodeCaster said, but take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging

Comment: Worth noting that your original code [should work fine under .NET Standard 2](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12496)

Comment: @DavidG i'll look into it

Comment: @JamesThorpe unfortunately i can't wait till .Net standard 2.0 :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which worked for me under Linux (Debian) and Windows 10  with .NET Core 2.1 Console Application:

- install log4net library (v2.0.8) with nuGet
- add the log4net.config in a Config folder
- add the static Logger class (code above)
- don't miss to adapt the value for 'file value' under linux (for
  example: /opt/log/mylog.log)

test log:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{  
   // all config stuff is done in the Logger class!      
   Logger.LogDebug("Debug Message from the main program");
   Logger.LogInfo("Info Message from the main program");
   Logger.LogWarn("Warn Message from the main program");
   Logger.LogError("Dummy Error Message from the main program");
}
```

log4net.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:Temp/ConsoleApp1.log"/>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="25MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <!-- minimum level to log -->
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Logger class:

```
public static class Logger
{
    private static ILog _log;
    private static LOGGING_MODE _logMode = LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE_AND_FILE;

    public static LOGGING_MODE LogMode { get => _logMode; set => _logMode = value; }

    private static void EnsureLogger()
    {
        if (_log != null)
            return;

        var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
        var configFile = GetConfigFile();

        // Configure Log4Net
        XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, configFile);
        _log = LogManager.GetLogger(assembly, assembly.ManifestModule.Name.Replace(".dll", "").Replace(".", " "));
    }

    private static FileInfo GetConfigFile()
    {
        FileInfo configFile = null;
        // Search config file
        var configFileNames = new[] { "Config/log4net.config", "log4net.config" };
        foreach (var configFileName in configFileNames)
        {
            configFile = new FileInfo(configFileName);
            if (configFile.Exists) break;
        }
        if (configFile == null || !configFile.Exists) throw new NullReferenceException("Log4net config file not found.");
        return configFile;
    }

    public static void LogDebug(string message)
    {
        EnsureLogger();
        if (_logMode == LOGGING_MODE.FILE || _logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE_AND_FILE)
            _log.Debug($"{message}");
        if (_logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE || _logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE_AND_FILE)
            Console.WriteLine($"{message}");
    }
    public static void LogInfo(string message)
    {
        EnsureLogger();
        if (_logMode == LOGGING_MODE.FILE || _logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE_AND_FILE)
            _log.Info($"{message}");
        if (_logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE || _logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE_AND_FILE)
            Console.WriteLine($"{message}");
    }
    public static void LogWarn(string message)
    {
        EnsureLogger();
        if (_logMode == LOGGING_MODE.FILE || _logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE_AND_FILE)
            _log.Warn($"{message}");
        if (_logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE || _logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE_AND_FILE)
            Console.WriteLine($"{message}");
    }
    public static void LogError(string message)
    {
        EnsureLogger();
        if (_logMode == LOGGING_MODE.FILE || _logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE_AND_FILE)
            _log.Error($"{message}");
        if (_logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE || _logMode == LOGGING_MODE.CONSOLE_AND_FILE)
            Console.WriteLine($"{message}");
    }
}
```

the enum

```
public enum LOGGING_MODE {CONSOLE, FILE, CONSOLE_AND_FILE};
```

Answer (score -1):

It should work please check [Loger Static Class Name](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#static-class-name) How do I get the fully-qualified name of a class in a static block?

You can easily retrieve the fully-qualified name of a class in a static block for class X, with the statement typeof(X).Name. Note that X is the class name and span an instance. However because the LogManager.GetLogger method is overloaded to take an instance of Type as well as string usually only the type of the class is required.

Here is the suggested usage template:

```
 public class Foo
 {
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Foo));
... other code
}
```

An equivalent and more portable solution, though slightly longer, is to use the declaring type of the static constructor.

```
public class Foo
{
   private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
... other code
}
```

Note: the .NET Compact Framework 1.0 does not support System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().

Comment: the last 1 doesn't work in .NET Core 1.1 and the first 1 isn't considered a "valid"(at my traineeship...) option unless no other options are available.

Comment: which version you are using

Comment: Version of what ? project.json dependecies : "log4net": "2.0.7" ,  global.json : "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"

Comment: there is another way to get name of the Class    this.GetType().Name;